# Trying to understand why Prisma (Composite Types for Mongo) is generating the wrong Types

Tags: typescript, mongodb, prisma

I can't deploy my api to prod because of the Composite Types/Embedded Documents from Prisma generating the wrong type (at least it's what I think and I could be 99% wrong). **It works on localhost.**

The errors I get when I build with tsc on Render.com

> error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ url: string; public_id: string; }'.
> error TS2339: Property 'public_id' does not exist on type 'string'.

```
model User {
  id           String       @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  email        String       @unique
  username     String
  profileImg   ProfileImage
  posts        Post[]
  Comment      Comment[]
  // and more
}

type ProfileImage {
  url       String @default("https://api.dicebear.com/6.x/lorelei/svg")
  public_id String @default("default_lorelei_id")
}
```

Now, I the two problems.

1. Creating a user. I thought not including the profileImg in the create function would directly cast the defaults I added to the Composite type. Removing the profileImg gives type error so I just added an empty object to make it somehow work on local. How should I handle it to make it the default values?

```
const user = await db.user.create({
    data: {
      username,
      email,
      password: passwordHash,
      followingIDs: [
        '657905e6efeb3ec3d3b81e37',
        '6579062fefeb3ec3d3b81e38',
        '6579064fefeb3ec3d3b81e39',
      ],
      profileImg: {}, // this one 
    },
  });
```

2. Updating profileImg. The type of profileImg that I get here is `{url: any, public_id: any}` which results in type error when building on Render.

```
await db.user.update({
    where: { id: userId },
    data: {
      profileImg: {
        set: {
          url: res.locals.imageDetails?.secure_url,
          public_id: res.locals.imageDetails?.public_id,
        },
      },
    },
```

One solution is to just make a new ProfileImg model instead of an embedded document/Composite Type.